# Timeline Moving very slow since upgraded to Alpha version(?) Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just upgraded from Unity Alpha 2019 3.0a3 to Alpha 3.0a10. Everything was working fine before the upgrading to any Alpha version. But now in my new scenes when I try to move the player-ship to create a master timeline for each new scene. The ship moves very, very slow in-game scene. Unity Engineer said this may be due to Unity still updating Alpha versions. Currently I not able to view assets I placed in scenes like rocks also.

My questions do I need to wait for until Unity completes the Alpha version updates? Or is there something I can do with my network working on my project? The project has 20 scenes but all times-lines except scene 1 and 2 moving very slow when I create it by the way scene 1 and 2 were created before upgrades to Alpha. There are no code errors in the code in scene 1 and 2 it works fine. It is the other timelines that move very slow.

I tried uninstalling Unity reverting back to the previous version using new assets. Nothing worked

Comment: The only reason you should ever be using an alpha version of Unity is if it's got a specific feature you're looking to test out; otherwise, you should be using any version with an `f` in it (the latest being 2019.1.12f1)

Comment: Thank you will look to download that version (2019.1.12f1) :)

Comment: Hi, Foggzie I reverted back to this version but all my terrains and some assets are all gone I trying to delete that current file and extract a new file.